# Putty title changes after login

Tags: ssh, putty

I am connecting with putty to a stock Ubuntu machine hosted at EC2, and notice the following:

When I connect, the title of the putty window appears at first as the hostname I enter (e.g. "myhostname.com"). After it's connected, the hostname changes to a different string - `user@domU-12-31-20-0a-81-AB: ~` (different on each machine).

This look like an ethernet address of sort, I'm not sure. It's really annoying because once I open 2-3 putty consoles I can't remember which is which.

Is it possible a ~/.bashrc script run from the machine itself changes the putty title? Somewhere else I should look into?

**Update:**

I forgot to mention this ... but I have tried this and the title I set up in the connection is shown briefly when connecting, but then overriden just like the default hostname title.

Comment: Deleted my answer, please update with that info :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's most likely updated by your **shell prompt** (**`$PS1`** in `~/.bashrc` or the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`). Look for `\e]2;` or `\033]2;` or a similar escape sequence.

Your given example looks like the usual "<user>@<host>:<path>" template, in which `domU-12-31-20-0a-81-AB` is the server's **hostname** as currently configured in the kernel. Most likely, it was assigned by an automated Xen domU creation tool based on your virtual server's Ethernet address.

You can change the current hostname by using `hostname newname`. To make it persist across reboots, look around in /etc – on every reboot, the hostname is **read from the file `/etc/hostname`** (other distributions may use `/etc/sysconfig/hostname` or similar).

Comment: It is my shell's prompt - but when I edit it later on using `PS1=myprompt` it doesn't stick. It seems editing the prompt inside .bashrc affects the putty title.

Comment: Check also $PROMPT_COMMAND

Comment: This is all useful information, for changing hostname and prompt, but it seems overkill to change your hostname just to achieve the effect of updating PuTTY's window title ... and it won't work if you're using tmux or something, which will update the window title with the title of the tmux window / "tab" you are in.  See @Michael Terry's answer below to change your PuTTY settings, that's what worked for me.

Comment: @ripper234 Please change the Accepted answer to the question below this one!!

Comment: This 'accepted' answer appears to be slightly wrong. The responsible variable is PROMPT_COMMAND, not PS1. PS1 is related, but almost certainly not what is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 82):

The easier answer to this question is two configuration changes in your Putty preferences for the session(s):

1. In `Window` -> `Behaviour` set your desired `Window title`.
2. In `Terminal` -> `Features` check `Disable remote-controlled window title changing`.

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Step 2 was exactly what I needed, way better than editing all the bashrc files out there

Comment: Yess, step 2 in your answer is *exactly* what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the title in putty (under linux) with this command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
```

in this case, it will display your USER name, your HOSTNAME and it wil Print out your current Working Directory

or you can do this, with a string of your choosing:

```
xterm -T "Title of My xterm" -n "Title when minimized"
```

Answer (score 2):

An exert from the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file is to run the following line to fix your title back to the default:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"
```

Comment: this does not work when using tmux or screen, why?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't used tmux, and I don't do much in `screen`... I'll have to research more

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way, and to piggy-back on @Michael Terry's answer:

If you've already opened your session and don't want to close it -
In Windows you can access the appropriate Putty configuration options by right-clicking the window title bar and select "Change Settings...". Keeping in mind changes here will not be saved once the session is closed.

Comment: Yes ... But you *can* save them if you want to, by going to "Session" in there, and selecting the current session, and clicking "Save".

Answer (score 1):

Nothing new to what grawity already said but a lot more detailed/mind-blowing article here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html

Relevant section for title manipulation is: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS and RedHat Linux you can create an empty file:

```
touch /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
```

And change its permissions with:

```
chmod 555 /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
```

Then `/ect/bashrc` won't change your PuTTY title, which you can set in PuTTY's settings:

```
Window -> Behaviour -> Window title
```

Answer (score 1):

If using MTpuTTy (useful for multiple parallel Putty sessions), use

> `Tools > Settings > General > Tab name > Show Display name`

.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable.  You can temporarily disable it with `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` however to make it apply globally you have to prevent that environment variable from being set before the first shell prompt appears.

On an EC2 running Amazon Linux 2, you can do this by editing `~/.bashrc` and at the end of it add the line `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Don't forget to edit the `.bashrc` for both `ec2-user` and `root` so that the titles remain unchanged even as you change user.