# How can I permanently change the title in putty title bar

Tags: windows-7, putty

I am using putty for ssh connections on my server.
but it displays the server name on the title bar.

I tried changing this by going in

`window --behaviour --then window title`

When I start putty then it displays the custom window title but when the connections gets established then it again changes to `username@servername`

Is there any way to permanently change the title?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to permanently change the title?

To permanently change the title (or other settings) in puTTY:

- First change the settings,
- Then **save** the changes.

[image]

> When I start putty then it displays the custom window title

Which seems to indicate that the above is working,

> but when the connections gets established it changes

Which might be the remote computer setting the title.

Either remove that from the reomve login scripts, or uncheckmark the permissions for that.

[image: PuTTY title changing permissions]

Comment: i tried that even that did worked for the single sessionas well. If you click on putty then it displays the chnaged title. then it asks for username and password for the ssh. once connected then it chnages the title to username@servername. did u tried youself

Comment: It works for me. I just got up. puTTY-ied into a host and my title is `My permanent title`. Which is the one I set yesterday before I posted. (And yes, it is a new session since I powered my computer off in between). 

Did you select session you wanted to modify before pressing save?

Comment: yes i did that. i reid everthing but the moment i got coonect with username and password , my title gets chaged. what should i do. i think this guy has same issue http://superuser.com/questions/510900/putty-title-changes-after-login?rq=1

Comment: Not the solution since that is a control character which change the window name.