# How compatible between different terminal types ($TERM)?

Tags: putty, tty, linux-terminal, terminal-emulator

For example, in [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) I set `TERM=xterm`, then I login to a Linux server and in the command line I run `export TERM=linux`, and then I start [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) with `screen -T screen` (means `TERM=screen`).

It's confusing to me how these `$TERM` types interact with each other because all this seems to work without a problem. Are different `$TERM` types designed in a way so they are compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately... if they were all compatible, $TERM wouldn't have been invented.

Nowadays, most terminal emulators are *mostly* compatible. But not entirely. They often imitate Xterm (which itself imitates a physical VT320, I think) – but not all of them support every single feature, and sometimes the basic features also differ.

For example, Urxvt is also Xterm-like when working with basic apps... until you notice that the codes used for special keys are all different! If you used TERM=xterm in Urxvt or vice versa, arrow keys or Home/End wouldn't work.

Your chosen TERM=linux has *very* limited features. It doesn't support underline or italic or bold text, it doesn't support 256-color or true-color formats, it doesn't support mouse input. It doesn't make *any* sense to set TERM=linux if you're using PuTTY or any other graphical terminal.

Fortunately, a more restrictive $TERM will often just make things look uglier and/or slower. (Colors will be fewer, or even absent. Programs will use a more tedious way of redrawing the screen if they're told they cannot use the usual fast one. And so on.) But doing the opposite though could make the programs completely unusable as programs would try to do things in a way the terminal simply can't cope with.

So generally, the *only* time you should change $TERM is when you know for sure that the terminal supports a better one. Both PuTTY and Screen are good examples as they support 256-color codes in recent versions, so it is okay to change TERM=screen to TERM=screen-256color and such. Tmux has a second example – it used to use TERM=screen too, but now has its own TERM=tmux, so it's okay to make such a change.

But you should never *need* to change TERM between completely different families (except in rare situations like network-serial, where the server has no way of detecting the correct value).

Use `infocmp -L` to compare two terminfo entries. (There will be some unnecessary differences and mistakes, but it'll still give you a good overview in general.)

Comment: for `TERM=linux`, i just tried `printf '\033[4mhello\n'` with putty (both putty and bash have `TERM=linux`) and it could display the underline. are you wrong with the underline statement or putty is smart enough and detected i'm trying to display the underline? (just to confirm i understand it right.)

Comment: and for putty to work fine with, e.g., `TERM=tmux`, it must have the `tmux`'s termcap/terminfo in its database. right?

Comment: You got it completely backwards. Terminals don't read $TERM – they _set_ $TERM in order to inform _shells and programs_ about what the terminal can do. For example, how did you know that `\e[4m` is the underline code? How does a program like 'ls' or 'vim' know the correct code for making text green? That's what the terminfo database is for – letting programs adapt to what the terminal expects to receive, not for making the terminal understand what programs send.

Comment: (Screen and tmux do both jobs: they act as programs and read the PuTTY-provided TERM=xterm on the outside, but also act as terminals and provide their own TERM=tmux on the inside.)

Comment: Based on my understanding, putty receives byte stream from the ssh server. For putty `\e[4m` is only some bytes. Since I configured TERM=linux in putty so it queries TERM=linux's terminfo and knows that `\e[4m` means *underline* so putty draws the underline for the following chars. So putty needs to have TERM=linux's terminfo in its database.

Comment: You still have it backwards. I'm not familiar with putty so there's a slim chance it does something like this, but I find it very unlikely. VTE used to try to do this, but stopped due to technical problems. Terminfo only describes a subset of the features; also sometimes a feature is composed of multiple escape sequences, e.g. `\E[H\E[2J` for `clear`, with this backwards thinking how would a terminal figure out what to do on a `\e[H` and what on a `\E[2J`? Terminals implement a certain hardwired behavior, and terminfo describes this behavior for the applications.

Comment: Also don't forget: Putty is typically run on Windows which has absolutely no terminfo available locally, so no, it cannot by design consult the terminfo database.

Comment: i tried like this: 1) in putty, set `TERM=notfound` and ssh to a linux server (and [allow remote side to change title](https://superuser.com/a/919770/105590) ), so the shell also has `TERM=notfound`; 2) in shell, run `printf '\033]0;hello\007'` and putty changed its window's title. so it's putty interprets the control sequence. i'm not sure if putty has a copy of terminfo database but at least it understands what these sequences mean in its code.

Comment: Your test doesn't make any sense. When you're writing control sequences by hand, you're just completely bypassing $TERM anyway. You're not **using** the terminfo database.

Comment: right. i just wanted to prove it's putty who interprets the sequences and display the text in color or underlined no matter whether putty has its copy of terminfo database or not.

Comment: and seems like putty never respects its $TERM since it always interprets `'\033]0;hello\007'` as a title change request. this can also explain why TERM=linux does not support underline (as you mentioned) but putty can still display underlined text.

Comment: The terminal emulator **has no way of knowing** what $TERM you have set. $TERM is never meant to go in that direction. It is always set **by** the terminal and respected by the programs running inside.

Comment: @user1686 *"TERM=linux has very limited features. It doesn't support underline or italic or bold text"* -- this is still confusing me a bit because `TERM=linux infocmp` would give me `bold=\E[1m, smul=\E[4m`. so what do you exactly mean by *"doesn't support underline or italic or bold text"*.